# Splitting on / inside a list in Python

Tags: python

I've got a list that contains the following:

```
x = ['1', '2/keys', '3']
```

Now the '2/keys' must be splitted. I figured it should be possible to make a list in a list?
But before splitting, I've got to check if there's a "`/`" at all.

The following code, that obviously doesn't work, is what I've got:

```
for numbers in x:
            if '/' in x:
                x[numbers].split('/')
```

Is it possible to have an outcome like:

```
x = ['1', ['2', 'keys'], '3']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close.

```
x = ['1', '2/keys', '3']
for ind, numbers in enumerate(x):
    if '/' in numbers:
        x[ind] = numbers.split('/')
print(x)
```

---

Or a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
x = [numbers.split('/') if '/' in numbers else numbers for numbers in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were really close, this is a nice way to do it with a list comprehension:

```
x = ['1', '2/keys', '3']
x = [elem.split('/') if '/' in elem else elem for elem in x ]
print(x)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['1', ['2', 'keys'], '3']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
x = ['1', '2/keys', '3']
x = list(map(lambda x: x.split("/") if "/" in x else x, x))
```

Result

```
['1', ['2', 'keys'], '3']
```

Not bad for a oneliner :)

EDIT:
@Rakesh solution is faster though:

```
$ python3 -m timeit "x = ['1', '2/keys', '3'];x=list(map(lambda x: x.split('/') if '/' in x else x, x))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.826 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit "x = ['1', '2/keys', '3'];x=[numbers.split('/') if '/' in numbers else numbers for numbers in x]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.454 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is a possible solution:

```
x = ['1', '2/keys', '3']
for i in range(len(x)):
    if '/' in x[i]:
        x[i] = x[i].split('/')
print(x)
```

And it will be the output:

> ['1', ['2', 'keys'], '3']